# Number of solution(s) of $(f(f(x))^2=\frac{3f^{-1}(x)}{2}+1$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

if $f :A \to [\frac{-1}{2} \: \: 0]$ is a real valued function such that $$f^3(x)-3xf(x)+x^3+1=0 \tag{1}$$ and if $f$ is Invertible, then find the number of solution(s) of $$(f(f(x))^2=\frac{3f^{-1}(x)}{2}+1 \tag{2}$$

My Try:

In $(1)$ if we plug in $x=0$ we get $f^3(0)=-1$ $\implies$ $f(0)=-1$ which means $x=0$ is not in set $A$

if we put $x=-1$ then $f^3(-1)+3f(-1)=0$ $\implies$ $f(-1)=0$ $\implies$ $f^{-1}(0)=-1$

But even though $x=-1$ is in $A$, $f(f(-1))$ does not exist.

hence neither $0$ nor $-1$ is the solution of $(2)$.

Can any one help me find any other solutions, looking for a better approach.

Comment: Does $f^3(x)$ mean $f(f(f(x)))$ or $(f(x))^3$? In my understanding usually it would mean the former one but it looks like you are using it as the latter one.

Comment: you are right, but it means $(f(x))^3$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.